# How to create this network setup, Router(IP 192.168.10.1) and connected 2PC in 2 ports: 192.168.30.1(in port enp4s0) and 192.168.30.1(in port enp5s0)

Tags: networking, ip, lan, subnet, segment

Required setup:
[image: network connection 1 on 1]

port:enp4s0 is assigned IP 192.168.10.23  => Connected to Machine 192.168.30.1 (gateway as 192.168.10.23)
port:enp5so is assigned IP 192.168.10.24  => Connected to Machine 192.168.30.1 (gateway as 192.168.10.24)

but only 1 machine(192.168.30.1 at enp4s0) is possible to connect from router not the other one via SSH

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use duplicate IP addresses. Each host needs to get its own address.

Also, all hosts need to share the same subnet prefix and mask, e.g. 192.168.10.0/24. Communication between hosts in different subnets requires a gateway/router.

Comment: Thanks, but I had made it work, It is possible using Static route for specific interface and have tested it